# Getting error: Cannot find module 'errno' running node script

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, webpack

I've just installed a fresh copy of Ubuntu 15.10, node 4.2.2 and npm 2.14.7 (with nvm) on a new machine. I have installed webpack and webpack-dev-server globally and installed my project dependencies with `npm i`.

Now when I try to run my node server I get the following errors:

```
module.js:339
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'errno'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:337:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:287:25)
at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
at require (module.js:385:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/node_modules/webpack-dev-middleware/node_modules/memory-fs/lib/MemoryFileSystem.js:7:14)
at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
at require (module.js:385:17)
```

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 2):

Node.js searches for modules in the `./node_modules/` directory in the path where the program is.

For example if you script is here `/home/user/scripts/somescript.js` you should have `/home/user/scripts/node_modules/`.

Just do `npm install errno` in here `/home/user/scripts/`.

Comment: Yes, I think 'errno' is a dependency of some other module that should have been installed when I did `npm i`. I seem to be having some difficulty getting all of the projects's dependencies to install correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that something had gone wrong with my `npm install` and my project dependencies were only partly installed. Just running `npm install` again didn't fix it. I did an `npm cache clean`, removed my `node_modules` directory and then ran `npm install` again. The problem was then resolved.